# Jooq selectFrom is not returning all the records

Tags: jooq

When I run the following query on a database function in postgresql

`select * from public.getData()  *** getData() is the db function`

This returns  record s like

| id | Name | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Test | en |
| 123 | Test-Fr | fr |
| 333 | Xyz | en |
| 333 | Xyz-fr | fr |

But when I use jooq generated code to call this same database function using

dslContext.selectFrom(callToFunction using jooq code) , it returns one record per id which means

| id | Name | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Test | en |
| 333 | Xyz | en |

I want this jooq also return all the records. Can someone help resolve this.

Regards

Comment: Can you post the stored function here?

Comment: Its a company internal code and not sure if I modify the code , will it help know the problem. Just to re-iterate that the function returns correct number of records when executed from PGAdmin/ Dbeaver. But the same function when executed from the jooq generated code, returns the records as mentioned in my original question.

Comment: Well, how can this be reproduced? It definitely doesn't sound like something that jOOQ causes for very obvious reasons...

Comment: The problem is solved and it was my code that was adding some extra spaces before calling the function. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Extra spaces cause this kind of wrong result? Now you got me curious :) You can answer your own questions here on stack overflow, perhaps it will be useful for some future visitor of this question.